# Vector subscript out of range - vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I have the following code. It's supposed to count the number of repetitions of the given letter in a given file. However, when i try to run this i get the Vector subscript out of range. Other people with the same error were trying to access undefined parts of it, but this doesn't seem to be an issue here i think.

```
struct letters
{
    char letter;
    int repetitions=0;
};


void howManyTimes(const string &output)
{
    ifstream file(output);
    vector <letters> alphabet;

    for (int i = 0; i < 'z' - 'a' + 1; i++)
    {
        alphabet[i].letter = 'a' + i;
    }

    string line;

    while (file.eof() == 0)
    {
        getline(file, line);
        for (char c : line)
        {
            if(c  >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                alphabet[c - 'a'].repetitions++;
            else if (c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')
                alphabet[c - 'A'].repetitions++;
        }
    }
    cout << alphabet[10].repetitions;
}
```

Comment: Where are you filling your vector with elements?

Comment: The vector needs to be initialized befor you use it. Otherwise use `push_back('a' + i)` instead of the `operator[]` to assign values.

Comment: You really should be using a `std::map` if you want to find the number of occurrences of unique items.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you ask about, but you should really take some time to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: _"i get the Vector subscript out of range. Other people with the same error were trying to access undefined parts of it, but this doesn't seem to be an issue here i think."_ Why do you think that? When your computer is telling you that it is literally that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> vector <letters> alphabet;  // (1)
>
> for (int i = 0; i < 'z' - 'a' + 1; i++)
> {
>     alphabet[i].letter = 'a' + i;  // (2)
> }
> ```

`(1)` creates an *empty* vector.

Inside the `for` loop in `(2)` you try to access items using the index `i` in an *empty* vector, so clearly your index is *out of range*.

You first have to populate the vector with some data, then you can access this data.

If you want to *add* new items to the vector, you can use `vector::push_back` (which is probably what you meant in `(2)`).

Answer (score 0):

> Other people with the same error were trying to access undefined parts of it, but this doesn't seem to be an issue here I think.

It is definitely an issue here:

```
vector <letters> alphabet; // Now size of the vector is 0.

for (int i = 0; i < 'z' - 'a' + 1; i++)
{
    // You are trying to access elements 0, 1, 2, ..., which do not exist.
    alphabet[i].letter = 'a' + i;
}
```

The simplest solution is to construct your vector with appropriate size:

```
vector <letters> alphabet('z' - 'a' + 1);
```

Comment: It should be noted that `'z' - 'a'` doesn't work on systems. It will work on systems using ASCII encoding (which is a vast majority of all systems), but it's not truly portable.

Comment: It's working! But it had to be
   `'z' - 'a' + 1`
And i had this 
`(c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')`
If wrong. Sign should be  `c < 'Z'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the part of your code where `alphabet` is expanded to accommodate the objects you plan to store in it. `std::vector` only resizes itself when you use the `push_back`, `insert`, `emplace` or other similar methods; it doesn't do so when accessing directly using the `operator[]` method.

At any rate, for a task like this, I'm not sure you'd want to use a vector, when a `std::map<char, int64_t>` would probably be a lot cleaner, and would let you preserve the syntax you're *trying* to use without tons of extra maintenance.

```
void howManyTimes(const string &output)
{
    ifstream file(output);

    map<char, int64_t> alphabet;

    string line;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        for (char c : line)
        {
            if(c  >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                alphabet[c - 'a']++;
            else if (c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')
                alphabet[c - 'A']++;

        }
    }
    cout << alphabet[10];

}
```

Comment: You should at least note that the loop condition is wrong, if you're going to reproduce it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I honestly did not notice that. I copied their code and made changes to the stuff I was focused on. I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

This program is really powerful for what the question is asking (makes me wonder how my students felt when I gave it as a homework assignment :) ). Do you have to use a struct? Let's assume not, and also assume we know the size of the alphabet, and that 'a' is the first letter and 'z' is the last letter:

```
vector<int> repetitions(26, 0);
char nextCharacter;
while( !file.eof() )
{
    cin >> nextCharacter;
    nextCharacter = tolower(nextCharacter);
    if(nextCharacter >= 'a' && nextCharacter <= 'z')
    {
        repetitions[nextCharacter - 'a']++;
    }
}
```

To check for a letter:

```
cin >> letterToQuery;
cout <<"The amount of occurrences of " << letterToQuery <<" is ";
cout << repetitions[tolower(letterToQuery) - 'a'] << endl;
```

If you don't know the size of your alphabet, the code changes to:

```
vector<int> repetitions('last_alphabet' - 'a' + 1, 0);
...
if(nextCharacter >= 'a' && nextCharacter <= 'last_letter')
```

And finally, if you DO have to use that struct, your code changes to:

```
struct Letter
{
    char letter;
    int repetitions=0;
};

vector<Letter> alphabet;
letter temp;
for(int i = 0; i < 'last_alphabet' - 'a' + 1; ++i)
{
    temp.letter = 'a' + i;
    alphabet.push_back(temp);
}

// then everything else is a similar structure
char nextCharacter;
while( !file.eof() )
{
    cin >> nextCharacter;
    nextCharacter = tolower(nextCharacter);
    if(nextCharacter >= 'a' && nextCharacter <= 'last_alphabet')
    {
        alphabet[nextCharacter - 'a'].repetitions++;
    }
}
```

To check for a letter:

```
cin >> letterToQuery;
cout <<"The amount of occurrences of " << letterToQuery <<" is ";
cout << alphabet[tolower(letterToQuery) - 'a'].repetitions << endl;
```

Notice, if you replace 'last_alphabet' with 'z', you get the current alphabet.